# Using binary operator in a sentence

Tags: spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\title{GROUP THEORY}

\maketitle

\section{Algebraic System}
It defines on binary operator \star  over a set A such that A \star A \rightarrow B

If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon, then the algebraic system is called "CLOSED"

Eg:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Set of integers is closed under +,-,\star\ operator.\
    \item Set of integers is not closed under / operator.\
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

i want

Group Theory

Algebraic System: It defines on binary operator * over a set A
such that A * A --> B

Eg 1. set of integers +,-,*
   2.set of integers /

(i want to replace * with star operator \star)

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Well, how can we know what do you want? ;) Please construct a [Minimal (non-)Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and possibly state _exactly_ what is the desired output you try to achieve.

Comment: i have edited please help me

Comment: please tell me how to enumerate two sentences

Comment: Sorry, what? I don't think I get what do you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The commands you like to use are only valid in math-mode. i.e. between two `$` signs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}% will help you to get real quotes ;-)
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}

\title{GROUP THEORY}

\maketitle

\section{Algebraic System}
It defines on binary operator $\star$ over a set $A$ such that
$A \star A \rightarrow B$

If the operator results in the same set that it operates upon,
then the algebraic system is called "CLOSED"

Eg:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Set of integers is closed under $+$, $-$, $\star$ operator.
    \item Set of integers is not closed under $/$ operator.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

In LateX you should declare everything that is math as such. That means that you use [`$…$` or `\(…\)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510) for inline and [`\[…\]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503) the `{equation}` environment (or one of the many other math environments) for display math.

[image: result]

---

BTW: `"CLOSED"` won’t give you the right quotes. If you load [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) and define `"` as quotation markers with `\MakeQuterQuote` you’ll get the right symbols in your PDF …