# What is \( used for?

Tags: math-mode, inline

I have seen the following syntax in a LaTeX example :

```
\( Inline math formula \)
```

What is the difference between those delimiters and $ ?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode?lq=1 (possible duplicate?)

Comment: It lets the reader know whether you are entering or leaving inline math.  For debugging purposes and clarity of code, it helps.  Of course, I still use `$` often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One advantage with `\(` and `\)` over dollar signs is that it is easier to match parenthesis in your editor.