# Update l2tabu and translation?

Tags: best-practices

The document l2tabu gives overview about the *sins* in latex: obsolete commands, packages, bad style.

However this document in it's most recent (german) Version is from 2011, the last translated english version even from 2007.

- Are there new *sins* to consider?
- which packages also have been succeeded by newer alternatives
- Are there people who might help to translate those documents into other languages?

Links:

- German version (2011): http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu
- English version (2005): http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l2tabu-english

I think these documents are very helpful for beginners considering the lots of ancient solutions to many problems and should therefore be updated regularly.

## ideas so far:

- [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode)
- scrpage2 → scrlayer-scrpage
- recommend utf8
- mention lua- and xetex
  in the encodings and font paragraphs
- tex gyre fonts

### maybe  one *issue* per answer is a good approach

Comment: Although I answered already: Your question will provoke opinion-based answers (see mine ;-))

Comment: I know ;) but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: Well, there is a certain level of agreement what should be done/not done in LaTeX

Comment: Perhaps a new document should be created, but I thought that this one was supposed to specifically reflect changes to core LaTeX. As such, I think it is useful to keep it focused on core-2e-based sins. It would be easy to turn it into a generic bunch-of-recommendations, but then it would be less useful. It is concerned with ***cardinal 2e sins*** and not intended, as I understand it, as a general list of Bad Things To Do in LaTeX documents, with additional information thrown in. It should be focused on LaTeX and not discuss contributed packages or it will become too hard to maintain.

Comment: @cfr: How about the `package tabu guide` ? ;-)

Comment: There should be a clear hierachy, like cardinal sins, don'ts, recommendations

Comment: @ChristianHupfer What about it?

Comment: I think he supposes to create a new document with this name ;)

Comment: @cfr: Sorry, typical typo of mine: What about a `package tabu guide` ;-)

Comment: @MaxNoe: Exactly!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Who would undertake to maintain such a monster? ;)

Comment: @cfr: Er... you? :)

Comment: The community.  Make it open, e.g. on github.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Never have I regretted so much my inability to down-vote comments :(.

Comment: @MaxNoe But then it would not make it into, for example, TeX Live.

Comment: Why not? Can a package on ctan not be a fork of a github repo?

Comment: @MaxNoe: No, there should be a clear list of authors/maintainers. If everybody is enabled to fiddle around in a document, it's most likely rejected

Comment: That's not the case. One would have a few maintainers. But a sophisticated system for others to participate,  issue handling, pull requests etc.

Comment: Actually I like the idea of such a 'package tabu guide' (not because it's my idea (if at all, I don't know))

Comment: The biggest tabu at the moment might be *not* to load `fixltx2e`.

Comment: Isn't the whole L3 dev going on on github? Will pushed some stuff a few hours ago.

Answer (score 2):

The `l2tabu` is a collection of 'don't do that' and from a personal point of view, I agree, that `\(...\)` is a good example which should be added, as a recommendation to replace `$...$` math mode.

I disagree on

- `scrpage2` (the change is too recent, in my point of view.)
- UTF8 --> as general input encoding?
- Lua- and XeTeX ... should be a taboo or a general recommendation?
- Tex Gyre fonts are an addition, there is no need to defy the older style of fonts.

Possible additions:

- Not using starred structure commands  (`\chapter*` ... etc.) in conjunction with 
  forcing them to appear in the TOC.
- Newer code/packages should be written with `xparse` and its `\NewDocumentCommand` etc. features instead of `\@ifnextchar[` stuff for macros with optional arguments
- For comparisons the `\if....` commands from `etoolbox` are cleaner (personal opinion) than `ifthen`
- Use `xstring` package for string manipulations
- `titlesec` and KOMA - classes/packages should not be used together
- `cleveref` is a package that should be loaded **after** `hyperref`

Comment: Concerning xe/luatex: mention them in the encoding/font section

Comment: I thought that the document was aimed at users rather than package authors, so I'm not sure that `xparse`, `etoolbox` or `xstring` really fit. Also, I had understood that `$...$` is fine - only `$$...$$` should be avoided. I don't think this kind of document can possibly hope to cover the complex issues of package loading order or not-actually-conflicting-but-don't-combine packages. There are just too many of these cases. What is wrong with using starred structure commands? (Genuine question - I'm not saying there isn't something, but I use these all the time.)

Comment: @cfr: You are right about the `etoolbox` etc. packages --> they are used by package/class authors mostly, but could be applied by 'normal' users of course. The statement about `starred` structures command is too short in my answer... I observed many questions about adding starred chapters to the TOC etc, causing 'problems'

Comment: Oh, right. Well, that's true. But saying they shouldn't be used in general would be wrong, I think. Unless there is a better way of producing unnumbered parts which you don't want in the ToC. (I rarely produce ToCs despite my current preoccupation with them.)