# A strange Missing $ inserted error

Tags: errors

For the following text snippet in my document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{quotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\say{For vertical axes deployment, $\theta_t$ = $\theta_r$ = 0 and for horizontal axes deployment, $\theta_t$ = \frac{$\pi$}{2} and $\theta_r$ = \frac{$-\pi$}{2} are used, \dots Hence, we conclude\dots, that the pathloss is dramatically higher for vertical axes deployment \dots}\\

\end{document}
```

I get

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
                $
l.396 ...higher for vertical axes deployment\dots}
                                                  \\
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong. Can anyone point out the problem?

TIA

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: shall update the question

Comment: I can't find a \say command in the quotes or amsmath packages. Could you explain what you want to acheive here? Is it a quotation of some other author?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `$` in a wrong way. It should be somthing like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
  For vertical axes deployment, $\theta_t = \theta_r = 0 $ and for horizontal axes
   deployment, $\theta_t = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\theta_r = \frac{-\pi}{2}$ are used,
   $\dots$ Hence, we conclude$\dots$, that the path loss is dramatically 
   higher for vertical axes deployment $\dots$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also for inline fractions, it is better to use `\pi/2` (instead of `\frac{\pi}{2}`) to get

[image]

Comment: Also, the use of dollar signs has been deprecated. For inline mathematics, it is now preferred to use `\( ... \)`, and for displayed mathematics, `\[ ... \]`.

Comment: @ChrisS `$` is deprecated? Since when? ;-)

Comment: @HarishKumar `$` to introduce maths has been deprecated since amslatex was developed; only (relatively) recently have people started pointing this out.

Comment: @HarishKumar See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/24113) and [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/24113).