# TeXstudio recognize $ in R code as that of the math mode

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio to typeset some R code with environment `Rcode`, `Routput` and command `\Rinline` (provided by `SASnRdisplay` package). Whenever there is a `$` sign appears in the code, TeXstudio will recognize it as the beginning of inline math and render everything after that differently. It does not affect the compiled file but it can be annoying while editing.

I can make `Rcode` and `Routput` to act like verbatim by changing the the custom highlighting option. However it does not work for `\Rinline` since it is not an environment. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: One mitigation of the problem would be to only use [`\( x \)` for (inline) math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode?lq=1) and to customize TXS to *not* render `$` as math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is currently not possible to prevent detection of `$` within commands as math mode.

As a workaround, you can add the special comment `%$` to the end of the line. This at least limits the incorrect highlighting to the line.