# TexStudio Special Comments for math mode over highlighting in minted environment

Tags: math-mode, minted, comments

Latex sudo noob here. I had a question regarding the answer to the question [TeXstudio recognize $ in R code as that of the math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231496/texstudio-recognize-in-r-code-as-that-of-the-math-mode)

How does one create the special comment listed in the answer?

It is used to reduce the incorrect highlighting in a minted like space for RStudio. I am trying to document some bash scripts and environemental variable references cause TexStudio to highlight whole swaths of text to math mode. The solution about would mitigate some of this but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks,

Will

**EDIT 1:** So the obvious answer would be to add a "%$" to the end of the line. This does not work at least for me. This would make my question "Am I doing it wrong?" or "Is there another solution?"

**EDIT 2:** Below is an image of the problem:
[image: Image of Minted/Math Mode problem with bash code]

Here it is with the suggested modification from the previous question:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What's the problem exactly? You just write `%$` at the end of the affected lines. At least, that's how I understand the answer. Have you tried that? Is the problem that it doesn't work? Or...?

Comment: So, please, add a minimal example showing the problem. Maybe with a printscreen of your highlighted code.

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. It works here. What version of TSX are you using? Did you check for some option in Configure menu?

Comment: I am using version 2.6.6. I thought it was the latest but maybe not.

Also I see no command options in the configure window.

Comment: Current version is 2.9.4. Upgrade and see is the issue is resolved.

Comment: @Sigur  It was a version issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `$` as part of some script (for example `$USER`) TeXstudio will interpret that dollar sign as opening math mode and will highlight as well.

So if you insert `%$` at the end of the line containing `$` in the script code it will not have effect since it is a comment (`%`).

And according to the solution you cited (I didn't tested) it should correct the highlight.

Comment: Well i tried using a %$ sign at the end. Is there another way i am supposed to format it?

Answer (score 0):

So as was suggested by @Sigur and @R. Schumacher in the origional post comments this was a version error... ProTex does not come with the latest TexStudio (2.6.6). Downloading the newest version (2.9.4) solved the issue.