# libertine/newtxmath: Spacing after italic f too small

Tags: kerning, libertine, newtxmath

When using the `libertine` package with `newtxmath`, the spacing after an italic "f" looks too small if a math character follows. Is there solution for this, apart from fixing all such occurrences manually?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
The spacing of $G$ and the preceding of is off.
Similarly for ``of $\mathsf{i}$''.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I also noted a problem with "of T" independent of mathmode. "of" and "T" seem to be too close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix it with the `mathtools` package, but you need to use `\(...\)` and not `$...$` (which is good anyway). The necessity for the italic correction is self-evident when Libertine is used, it's less so with other fonts.

Compare the two versions: the second one looks right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\mathtoolsset{mathic=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
The spacing of $G$ and the preceding of is off.
Similarly for ``of $\mathsf{i}$''.
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
The spacing of \(G\) and the preceding of is off.
Similarly for ``of \(\mathsf{i}\)''.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Note: never use `minimal`, which is just for testing packages, not output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I never use `minimal` in my documents. I just got the impression here on stackexchange that it is the preferred document class for MWEs.

Comment: Where can I find something about `$` vs `\(`? This is notoriously hard to search for, I just found http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/inline-math-mode/.

Comment: Ah, this is discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode