# How I can get get Null values in table using pgfplotstable?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I am creating a table using pgfplotstable in LaTeX. But the problem is, I want first column of table blank. But we never leave any values, table should be balanced in pgfplotstable.I define "nan" to keep column blank. But did not work. What I should do?

**pgfexample.tex**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}

\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[h!]
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep = comma,
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/S/.style={column name={$\leq$}}
  columns/A/.style={string type,column name={$\sigma$}},
 ]
{LSDtable.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**LSDtable.csv**

```
#LmitStateDesign table's data
S,A,B,C,D
nan,0.00375,360.53,0.0025,344.45
nan,0.0037,360.01,0.00245,343.42
```

I want first column of table blank. Suggest me something to solve problem.

Comment: read the `create on use` key  in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just leave them blank in your `csv`-file. To be able to write math inside a `tabular`, or any non-math-environment, you need to put your math inside `\(math\)` for inline math, and `\[math\]` for display math. You were really on the right track here, as you have written `$\sigma$` elsewhere. Using `$`-signs  works here too, but it is advisable in `LaTeX` to use `\(math\)` and `\[math\]`.

For more information see [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode)

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{LSDtable.csv}
#LmitStateDesign table's data
S,A,B,C,D
\(\leq\),0.00375,360.53,0.0025,344.45
,0.0037,360.01,0.00245,343.42
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[h!]
 \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep = comma,
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
  columns/S/.style={string type,column name={}},
  columns/A/.style={string type,column name={$\sigma$}},
 ]
{LSDtable.csv}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sir, But I want to print \sigma in place of column A and \leq in place of S.

Comment: sorry, not sure why I removed that part. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Sir, I want LaTeX symbol in table data. I want 1st column header blank (not 'S') and \leq symbol parallel to 0.00375 value. I am unable to do this using pgfplotstable. Suggest me good tutorial or help me.

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman that was not in your first question, but really, no problem. See new answer.

Comment: Thanku so much, Runar. You solved m problem. IS parenthesis compulsary, when we want to define latex symbol in .csv?

Comment: @ManpreetDhiman see updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41725/discussion-between-manpreet-dhiman-and-runar-trollet).