# beamer \usebackgroundtemplate \vbox to \paperhigth too low

Tags: beamer, header-footer, backgrounds, colorbox

In my presentation on each frame (including title frame) I need a background image and a footer line on each frame with the companies name (so that the image begins direclty upon this footer line).

I managed to add the image and the footer line as needed using  `\usebackgroundtemplate \vbox to \paperhigth` taken from this answer: [Beamer background image centered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26458/beamer-background-image-centered)
And the colorbox part from this answer: [How to make \colorbox fill the color between underline and overline of a text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324702/how-to-make-colorbox-fill-the-color-between-underline-and-overline-of-a-text)

But my footer line starts too low so that the text in it is cut by the frame edge:
[image: text cut at frame edge]
How do I raise the \colorbox (and the picture not shown) by about .5em?
Desired output is:
[image: text completely visible]

This is my sample code:

```
    \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usepackage{color}
    \definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.76, 0.76, 0.76}
    \definecolor{dark-gray}{rgb}{0.36, 0.36, 0.36}
    \usebackgroundtemplate{%
        \vbox to \paperheight{
            \vfil       
            \colorbox{dark-gray}{
                \makebox [\paperwidth][l]{
                   \tiny\color{gray}{
                      \hspace{2em}\textcopyright Company Name
                   }
                }
             }
        }
    }

    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{ } 
     test
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the height of the box:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.76, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{rgb}{0.36, 0.36, 0.36}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \vbox to \paperheight{
        \vfil       
        \colorbox{dark-gray}{
            \makebox(442,8)[lt]{
               \tiny\color{gray}{
                  \hspace{2em}\textcopyright Company Name
               }
            }
         }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

To use other than the default coordinates:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.76, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{dark-gray}{rgb}{0.36, 0.36, 0.36}
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \vbox to \paperheight{
        \vfil       
        \colorbox{dark-gray}{
                \setlength{\unitlength}{\paperwidth}
            \makebox(1,0.02)[lt]{
               \tiny\color{gray}{
                  \hspace{2em}\textcopyright Company Name
               }
            }
         }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can I use length aliases like `\pagewidth`, `\textheight`?

Comment: No. But you could change the unit of the coordinates, see my edit.

Comment: This lets the grey bar begin after the image. :o(

Comment: solved, i needed an empty line between image and colorbox... :o)