# How to include math symbols in itemize?

Tags: itemize

I want to code the below lines of the image in latex.
[image]

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item [m] - Number of training examples
   \item [x] - "Input"  variables / features
   \item [y] - "Output" variable / "target" Variable
   \item [(x,y)]  - One training example
   \item x^(i),y^(i) - i^{th} training example
\end{itemize}
```

I have given a try, but i am facing an error. I couldn't identify what's the issue behind. Please help me.

```
 The error i am facing is 

  ! Missing $ inserted.
  <inserted text> 
            $
     l.40         \item [x^(i),y^(i)] - i^{th} training example
  ? 
   ! Extra }, or forgotten $.
```

Comment: You should use the environment  description. This will make your code more semantic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use math mode for math symbols, i.e. enclose em with `$` or in `\(…\)` (see [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/4918)). Furthermore I’d use a `description` list in this case as this would match the input better …

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [$m$] Number of training examples
\item [$x$] ``Input''  variables / features
\item [$y$] ``Output'' variable / ``target'' Variable
\item [$(x,y)$]  One training example
\item [$x^(i),y^(i)$] $i$-th training example
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore I’d write `$i$-th` instead of the superscript to prevent confusion with “*i* to the power of *th*”. You also missed the brackets at the last item.

And you may take a look at the `csquotes` package to get the right quotes.

Comment: Maybe you should cross out the recommendation for `$`(see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/124577)

Comment: Yep, thanks for the comment. Had it in mind but forgot to add it ;-)

Comment: Note that using square bracket characters _inside_ the item symbol will trigger errors, so replace literal brackets by `\lbrack` and `\rbrack`

Comment: As for alle optional argument you can also enclose the whole argument in braces like `\item [{$[1,2]$}]`.