# sequences and equations within text in latex

Tags: align

I am struggling to insert the circled passage into latex, if anyone can translate it for me.

When i have tried to insert it the equations within the text they  start on a new line

[image: sssssss]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `\(x^{*(b)} = x^{*}_1, \dots, x^{*}_n\)`. That's inline.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post the code that you have so far (strip the paragraphs before and after, but keep the preamble). This way we see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure why anybody would have to "struggle" here: All one has to do is use nested `enumerate` environments. No special packages required. Be sure to use inline math mode rather than some display math environments for the mathy stuff.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\dots\ $\hat{\theta}$ is obtained as follows. % end of prior sentence 
\begin{enumerate}
\item For each bootstrap replicate, indexed $b=1,\dots,B$:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Generate sample $x^{*(b)} = x^{*}_1, \dots, x^{*}_n$ by sampling \dots
  \item Compute the $b$\textsuperscript{th} replicate \dots
  \end{enumerate}
\item The bootstrap estimate of $F_{\hat{\theta}}(\cdot)$ is the \dots
\end{enumerate}

The bootstrap is applied to \dots % start of paragraph that follows the enumeration
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the nested enumeration was the OP's problem so much as not being aware of the `$...$` syntax for inline mathmode.

Comment: @dbmag9 - Your guess as to the cause of the OP's struggles may well be better than mine.

Comment: Have you read the post about `\(` and `$`? Very good stuff ;)

Comment: @TeXnician - Do you maybe have [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305471/5001) in particular in mind? :-)