# Written on same line equation and string

Tags: math-mode, equations, formatting

I have written "`hello world x (become) E`"

my code is:

```
hello world \[\in {E}\]
```

but the result is: two line

[image]

Comment: `\[` and `\]` enter display-math mode; use `$\in E$` (or `\(\in E\)` if you prefer).

Comment: @SeanAllred good comment please written you answer for i put +1

Comment: I suggest having a look at http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would've preferred to close this as a duplicate, but alas, I cannot find this question anywhere :( This is pretty basic syntax stuff, so I would find a nice introduction to LaTeX (such as egreg suggests in the comments above).

`\[` and `\]` is shorthand to enter display-math mode; use `$\in E$` (or [`\(\in E\)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/17423) if you prefer).