# Problem with compilation in arabtex

Tags: arabtex

I'm working with this files:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{arabbook}
%%%%%%%%%%% packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{arabtex} 
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}% R ensemble des nombres reels
\usepackage{graphicx}% ajouter des photos
\usepackage{pstricks}% pour dessiner
%%%%%%%%%%%% ab3ad AlsfhA
\textwidth= 15truecm % 
\textheight= 22.27truecm % 
\hoffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
\voffset= -1.5 cm%truecm %
%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
% `dm Alt^skyl 
\novocalize
% bdAyt Alw_tyqT
\rhead{\RL{Alf.sl Al'awl}}
\lhead{\RL{`nwAn Alf.sl}}
\begin{document}
\begin{arabtext}



$$
\exp(x)=0
$$
\section{fkrT}


\newpage
 \tableofcontents



\end{arabtext}
\end{document}
```

I have this error : Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

How to correct this ?

Thank you

Comment: Read the documentation (arabtex-doc.pdf). There are quite a number of things shouldn't put inside a arabtext environment. And consider to use something more modern  -- the documentation is from 1993 and the style from 2003.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer how i can find it ? have you suggestion to ameliorate it

Comment: For the documentation, see http://baobab.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/ifi/bs/research/arab_e.html The more modern packages to which Ulrike Fischer refers are `arabxetex` and `arabluatex`. `arabxetex` has been around longer, whereas `arabluatex` is still being developed, so you’ll probably want to start with `arabxetex`.

Comment: @Thérèse i don't understand  what you say what i must do ?

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
$$
\exp(x)=0
$$
```

with this:

```
$\exp(x)=0$
```

You can also use `$$\exp(x)=0$$`, `\[ \exp(x)=0 \]`instead or even the \equation environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\exp(x)=0
\end{equation}
```

but in these three cases you have to put it under the first `\chapter` or `\section` command. See the commends below for more.

Comment: Did you test `\[` and `\begin{equation}`? For me this leads to the same error as reported in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I checked only the first out of the three solutions i suggest. I have Live Tex installed. I compiled it with Tex Maker. The second and the third one actually don't work.

Comment: This might be due to LaTeX seeming to expect text before the first `section` command. `\[` and `\begin{equation}` result in display math while `$` starts in line math. The two display math commands work if one enters a single letter or more text before the `\section` command.

Comment: Additionally, it should be noted, that using `\(`and `\)` in LaTeX should be preferred over using `$`. (See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/134144)

Comment: That seems quite reasonable...

Comment: Please how i can ameliorate this package? and how i can center the equation ? @theohadoulis

Comment: @theohadoulis \begin{equation} and \[ gives the sames error