# What are the differences between $...$, $$...$$, \(...\), and \[...\]?

Tags: math-mode

The title says it all. I haven't been able to find the answer yet, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On `$$` vs `\[` see [Why is \\[ ... \\] preferable to $$ ... $$?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). On `$` vs `\(` see [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/510).

Comment: [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/106162) covers the other.

Comment: I already knew most of the differences discussed in these questions. The main thing is \(...\) vs \[...]\]. Thanks anyways!

Comment: So do these questions answer the question you're trying to ask? Because the difference between `\(` and `\[` is inline vs. display math.  The corresponding `$` versions are TeX (not LaTeX) versions of these.

Comment: @AlanMunn the inline vs. display answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I've added an answer explaining the broad distinction with links to the other questions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Math mode has two main modes: display mode and inline mode.  Inline mode is for math that is included within a line or paragraph of text, and display mode is for math that is set apart from the main text.

### Inline math

The TeX delimiters for inline math are `$` and `$`.

The LaTeX delimiters for inline math are `\(` and `\)`.

Although it's possible to use `$`...`$` for inline math as well in LaTeX.  See the following question for more discussion.

- [Are \( and \) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/106162)

### Displayed math

The TeX delimiters for displayed math are `$$` and `$$`.

The LaTeX delimiters for displayed math are `\[` and `\]`.

Unlike the delimiters for inline math, you should *not* use the TeX form of the delimiters in LaTeX.  See the following question for discussion.

- [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: Notably, inline `$` ... `$` syntax _is_ documented in _LaTeX: A Document Preparation System_ by Lamport, whilst `$$` ... `$$` syntax is not.