# How to put math below and centered inside environment

Tags: equations

I'm having a bad time trying to figure out how to place `Example 1` in the left and the math material one line below and centered. How do I do that?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newtheorem{xmp}{Example}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xmp}
        $ \mathbf{A}_{4\times 4}=\begin{pmatrix}
        5 & -2 & 4 & 7 \\
        -1 & 3 & 0 & -6 \\
        2 & -9 & 5 & 8 \\
        0 & 3 & 4 & 1
        \end{pmatrix} $
    \end{xmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: some reading of basic latex documentation would be useful.  regarding math, i recommend documentation for `amsmath` and `mathtools`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? Replace your dollar signs `$` with `\[` and `\]` to format your equation in display mode.

For further reading see [What are the differences between $...$, $$...$$, \(...\), and \[...\]?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/410863/what-are-the-differences-between-and?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{xmp}{Example}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xmp}
    \[
        \mathbf{A}_{4\times 4}=\begin{pmatrix}
        5 & -2 & 4 & 7 \\
        -1 & 3 & 0 & -6 \\
        2 & -9 & 5 & 8 \\
        0 & 3 & 4 & 1
        \end{pmatrix} 
    \]
    \end{xmp}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. To improve the readability of the contents of the 4x4 matrix, you may want to recommend that the OP load the `mathtools` package (a superset of the `amsmath` package) and replace (a) `\begin{pmatrix}` with `\begin{pmatrix*}[r]` and (b) `\end{pmatrix}` with `\end{pmatrix*}`. That way, the numbers will be right-aligned instead of centered, greatly improving the overall appearance and readability of the matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much both of you. It solved my problem and it got much better looking.