# Where is the error in this definition?

Tags: math-mode, definition

I wanted to ask if you could tell me why the formula in the comment area doesn't work in the {defn} area without '%'.

```
 \begin{defn}
  Let $n \times n$ \emph{Hessenberg-Matrix} $\pmb{H}_n$ with coefficients $\beta_j^k$ be

$$\pmb{H_n}=\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_0^0 & \beta_1^1 & \cdots &\beta_{n-1}^{n-1}\\
1  & \ddots & \quad & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots  \\
0 & \dots & 1  & \beta_0^{n-1}   
\end{pmatrix}.$$

%and \pmb{\pi}(t)= \[\pi_0(t),\pi_1(t),\dots,\pi_{n-1}(t)\]^T
\end{defn}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\[`...`\]` is the preferred way to initiate/set a display math equation, rather than `$$`...`$$`. See [Why is `\[` ... `\]` preferable to `$$` ... `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5764).

Two things you need to change in order for your definition to compile:

1. You need to set math content in math mode, so use `$`...`$` (or [`\(`...`\)`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/5764)).
2. Vector notation uses `[`...`]`, not `\[`...`\]`, which is used for a display math equation (see above).

You're probably after

```
and $\pmb{\pi}(t) = [ \pi_0(t), \pi_1(t), \dots, \pi_{n-1}(t) ]^T$.
```

As an aside, keep the document content and structure together by not leaving a blank line between the preceding and following text for a display equation:

```
Let $n \times n$ \emph{Hessenberg-Matrix} $\pmb{H}_n$ with coefficients $\beta_j^k$ be
\[
  \pmb{H_n} = \begin{pmatrix}
    \beta_0^0 & \beta_1^1 & \cdots & \beta_{n-1}^{n-1} \\
        1     &  \ddots   & \quad  &      \vdots       \\
     \vdots   &  \ddots                                \\
        0     &   \dots   &    1   &   \beta_0^{n-1}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
and $\pmb{\pi}(t) = [ \pi_0(t), \pi_1(t), \dots, \pi_{n-1}(t) ]^T$.
```

Comment: Rather than `\pmb`, `\bm` from the `bm` package is recommended.