# Nested Chemformula exceeds TeX Capacity

Tags: chemformula, capacity

Here is an MWE of the problem at hand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

    $\varphi_{\ch{N2}}$%chemformula as index works

    \ch{C + O2 + N2 -> CO2 + N2}%regular equation

    \ch{C + O2 + $\varphi$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}%escaped math works

    %\ch{C + O2 + $\varphi_{\ch{N2}}$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}%throws error when nested

\end{document}
```

In the code with its comments, the problem is explained: using `chemformula` and its command `\ch`, indices may be created, even in math mode, see the first line of code.

Formulating a longer equation within `\ch` but then also trying to escape math symbols who themselves have indices typeset using `\ch` results in nested `\ch` commands. These throw and error

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000]. ...+ O2 + $\varphi_{\ch{N2}}$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}
```

when compiled.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Roughly: `\ch` calls `\chemformula_ch:nn`, which parses the formula and stores it into `\g__chemformula_output_tl` before using that global variable.  Parsing the big formula puts `\__chemformula_ch_main:n {C + O2 + $\varphi _{\ch {N2}}$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}` in the global variable.  Among other things this runs `\ch{N2}`, which *adds* `\__chemformula_ch_main:n {N2}` to the global variable.  When the variable is run it contains two `\__chemformula_ch_main:n`.  The first includes `\ch{N2}`, which adds a third `\__chemformula_ch_main:n` and runs the variable...  Sorry, I won't have time to dig more.

Comment: I hope I'm showing my full ignorance here but ... Perhaps this means, one of the calls needs to be expanded immediately rather than stored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is quite easy actually: use `\chcpd` inside:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

$\varphi_{\ch{N2}}$%chemformula as index works

\ch{C + O2 + N2 -> CO2 + N2}%regular equation

\ch{C + O2 + $\varphi$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}%escaped math works

\ch{C + O2 + $\varphi_{\chcpd{N2}}$ N2 -> CO2 + N2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but notice how this is not what I am looking for. The index for `\varphi` is now set in plain math-mode, removing the capabilities of `chemformula` I was originally after.

Comment: @HansLollo indeed. It *should* work, though, so this looks like a small bug… There is another clean solution, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of playing with `\ensuremath` and `\mathrm` seems to do the job.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand{\varphich}[1]{\ensuremath{\varphi_{\mathrm{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

without ch - shows as text: \varphich{N2}

ch in it - shows as chemistry: \(\varphi_{\ch{N2}}\)%chemformula as index works

equation 1: \ch{C + O2 + N2 -> CO2 + N2}%regular equation

equation 2: \ch{C + O2 + \(\varphi\) N2 -> CO2 + N2}%escaped math works

equation 3: \ch{C + O2 + \varphich{\ch{N2}} -> CO2 + N2}%throws error when nested

\end{document}
```

I also used the `\(` `\)` designations for in-line math based on [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode).

Comment: This does in fact not work for me. XeLaTex throws the error `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500]` (which is likely what @BrunoLeFloch referred to), while pdfLatex returns `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255]`, similar but still different to the one above. I am not knowledgeable enough to understand why these are different.

I doubt that extending the TeX capacity works here.

Comment: Gosh. Then I am lost. The above compiles on my TeXLive install under macOS.

Comment: I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [semantic nest size=500].` on macOS. I tried with TeX Live from 2012 to 2018; up to 2017 the failure is with `grouping levels`.