# align section content with first line in runin section

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, alignment

I'm currently using the following layout for my weekly exercises at my university:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% section title format and spacing
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\Large}{Exercise \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{0pt}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{(\alph{subsubsection})}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.75em}

% subsubsection indentation
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{\leftskip1em\svsubsubsection}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{section}{1}
    \subsection{}
    \subsubsection{}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsubsection{}
        \[ some\ equation \]
    \subsection{}
\end{document}
```

How can I align all lines with the start of the first in a subsection, as shown by the following image: [image]

And how can I make `\[ \]` math environments start in the first line of the subsection?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `aligned` environment:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}% <-- better to load this (it also loads amsmath)

% section title format and spacing
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\Large}{Exercise \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{0pt}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{(\alph{subsubsection})}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.75em}

% subsubsection indentation
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{\leftskip1em\svsubsubsection}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{section}{1}
    \subsection{}
    \subsubsection{}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsubsection{}
    $\begin{aligned}[t]
        F &= ma \\
        E &= mc^2
     \end{aligned}$
    \subsection{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers my second question. I'm sorry that I've put two questions in one post, but I really didn't want to create a second question for a small problem like this.
Anyways, I was told to not use `$` for math mode as it's TeX style and not LaTeX. But now I see you using it with a reputation of 162k, so what's the truth about `$` and `\( \)`?

Comment: @jkhsjdhjs: The reason for keeping unrelated question separate are so that they may also help others in the future, should they encounter a similar problem. Having may unrelated questions lumped together make it difficult to find.

Comment: @jkhsjdhjs:  @jkhsjdhjs:  As per you question regarding `\(...\)`. Yes, using `\(...\)` is what is recommended as per [Are \\( and \\) preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/4301), but I got used to using `$...$` and old habits are hard to break. On the other hand, using `$$...$$` for display math should definitely be avoided as per [Why is \\[...\\] preferable to $$..$$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/4301).

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be much easier and simpler to use an `enumerate` environment with *adhoc* parameters. Here is a possible code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% section title format and spacing
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\sffamily\Large}{Exercise \arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}{0pt}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{(\alph{subsubsection})}{0pt}{}[]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{0.5em}{0.75em}

% subsubsection indentation
\let\svsubsubsection\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{\leftskip1em\svsubsubsection}

\begin{document}

    \setcounter{section}{1}
    \subsection{}
    \begin{enumerate}[wide = 0.6em, label=(\alph*), leftmargin=*]
      \item \lipsum[1-2]
    \item\leavevmode\vspace{-\baselineskip}\useshortskip \[ \text{some equation} \]
    \lipsum[11]
    \end{enumerate}
    \subsection{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd prefer a solution without an additional environment, just \subsubsection, if that's even possible.