# Math mode trouble with backslash in Texstudio

Tags: math-mode, editors, auto-completion

In text studio, when you start typing `\(` it automatically fills in to
`\(\)` with the cursor in the middle. As I try to type let's say a greek letter such as "\gamma", the editor automatically uses the backslash from `\)`, meaning that I end with `\(\gamma)` instead of `\(\gamma\)` of course.

Is there a way for the editor to stop trying to auto-complete that aspect as it is always doing it wrong?

Comment: You could write `$\gamma$` to avoid the problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I would like to avoid using the TeX delimiters if possible

Comment: In contrast to equations, using tex delimiters does not make much difference for inline math, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305471/36296