# The LaTeX syntax for this probabilistic formula

Tags: equations, best-practices, math-operators

I would like to create a math formula as follows. How do I write it in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What have you tried so far, how far did you get? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recommend reading one of the guides listed here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
f\sim\mathcal{GP}(\mu(x),K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}';\theta))
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Next time, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you tried.

Comment: I'd suggest just a teeny tiny correction: `\mathbf{x}'` instead of `\mathbf{x'}`. It doesn't make a practical difference here but I think it is semantically better. (IMO of course.)

Comment: @campa Yes, it's better, corrected, thanks!

Comment: I know texperts use \[\] but what do you use for inline expressions? $expression$

Comment: @santimirandarp I this this post can be helpful to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode

Comment: thanks @CarLaTeX you're always helpful :)

Comment: @santimirandarp You're welcome!

Comment: But in the end you still complied with the work order.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sorry, I don't understand your comment