# Writing Persian text in latex in vs code

Tags: right-to-left, persian, vscode

I want to use VS code as my new latex editor because it offers lots of great features. But since I write lots of Persian text, VS code doesn't show them correctly. It doesn't have an RTL option to format the Persian text. I have searched for extensions or settings but I couldn't find anything. Is there any way I can write Persian text in VS code and it shows the text right-to-left in the editor as in Tex studio?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It may well be that someone here knows both, RTL languages and VS code. However, if you don't receive reasonable answers, try some VS code forum.

Comment: I just took a persiantex example from here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610437/how-to-import-a-certain-open-math-font-xepersian/610442#610442  and pasted it into an empty (windows) visual  studio code window and it [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eK9N.png) I can not read the text but I think it looks the same as the original as rendered by the browser

Comment: @gernot whom were you referring to as those geniuses?

Comment: _unless offensive or spam, should be given some time before being closed_ @gernot  I agree.

Comment: _post a question relevant to you, and get closed without comment. At least I would never return again._ that's why I left SO, what.thedailywtf.com is better than this jargon this internet-made bullshit.

Comment: What is the extension you use? choose from here, if you want: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=latex&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:
The order of words in a line is broken when you use an RTL language in vscode, however it is compiled in the right order. Most editors have this problem and I am not aware of any one which has solved this problem. The same is true for your attached picture. I am wondering if this problem is unsolvable or not because it has been around for many years!

Comment: @HoseinRahnama really, vs code can't do rtl? that's surprising. You can use any editor that can typeset rtl

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you have any specific suggestion for such an editor? :) I may post a new question to illustrate the problem completely. I will tag you to the question then.

Comment: @HoseinRahnama https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/what-a-good-text-editor-with-rtl-right-to-left-support but you are right about vscode https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/86667  emacs is the editor I use

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I found [this post] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/493146/latex-editor-that-correctly-supports-mixed-rtl-presentation-windows) related, which is illustrating the problem. An answer is also given with emacs.