# Is there any reason to use \begin{equation} and \end{equation} instead of the two $ signs?

Tags: equations

Sorry if this question has already been answered somewhere. I tried searching it up in google but I couldn't find anything.

My question: If I want to write an equation in LaTeX, when do I use `$...$` (or `$$...$$`) and when do I use  `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`? Are there any (dis-)advantages or do they do the same thing?

I am new to LaTeX so this is probably a very trivial question.

Comment: `$...$` is for *inline* math. As for `$$` see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$ … $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917)

Comment: See also [Are `\(` and `\)` preferable to dollar signs for math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/82917)

Comment: Parsing the code is also much easier when start and end is different.

Comment: Thank you guys. I get it now :) [I don't know how to upvote comments so just take my virtual like]

Comment: @Lorun depending on what you have access to you should be able to upvode via the arrows next to the comments.

Comment: if you saw a latex tutorial that suggested that `$$` is valid syntax you should contact the author and see if it can be fixed. But apart from that `equation` adds an equation number and `$$` does not.