# In TikZ, is it possible to isolate every character of an expression in a node as its own node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I often find myself typing equations into a node of a tikz picture. I then often find that I want to isolate certain characters in the equation and define them as a node.

For instance, consider the following figure.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {$e^{i\pi}+1=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like it if in this figure I could define each character `e`, `i`, `pi`, `+`, `1`, `=`, and `0` as its own node. Is this possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `\subnode` command from [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) is designed for this sort of situation.  It fakes a node around text that's inside a `\node`.  It does need a few compilation runs to settle (it took 3 for this code for me) and you must remember the `remember picture` key on the tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582127/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex,remember picture]
  \node (eipi) at (0,0) {\(e^{i\pi}+1=0\)};
\node at (0,-1) {\(\subnode{e}{e}^{\subnode{i}{i}\subnode{pi}{\pi}}+\subnode{one}{1}=\subnode{zero}{0}\)};
\draw[<-] (e) to[out=-90, in=90] ++(-2,-1) node[below] {Base of natural logarithm};
\draw[<-] (i) to[out=135, in=0] ++(-2,1) node[left] {A square root of \(-1\)};
  \draw[<-] (pi) -- ++(0,-2) node[below] {Area of a unit circle};
  \draw[<-] (one) to[out=-45, in=180] ++(2,-1) node[right] {Unity};
\draw[<-] (zero) -- ++(2,0) node[right] {Zilch};
\draw[<-] (eipi) -- ++(0,1) node[above] {An ugly equation};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Annotated equation with subnodes]

Comment: This has become my new workhorse! It's helping a lot with beamer slides that I'm writing for the course I'm teaching. 

I'm curious why you've started the math text in the nodes with `\(`. I was writing a document earlier that didn't work correctly when I used `$` but then did work when I switched to `\(`. Any idea why?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick I don't know of a reason why it wouldn't work with `$`.  If you have an example then feel free to send it my way (open an issue on https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark or email me directly - my email is in the tikzmark documentation).  In general, though, `\(` is to be preferred to `$`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/86 for a bit more on that.

Comment: I'll see if I can build a MWE. The document I was building was very complex so it's definitely possible there was something else going on.

Comment: So I just tried to replicate my issue... and couldn't. However, I'm now almost positive that I was recycling a node name in another tikzfigure, which causes problems with `remember picture`.  When I edited my original document I must have changed the node name in addition to switching  the `$` to `\(`.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Well, if it does resurface then do let me know.  I'm pleased to hear you got it working.