# What are brackets do in new command definition?

Tags: syntax

In [an article about defining new commands](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Commands) I saw an example

```
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}

The set of real numbers are usually represented 
by a blackboard bold capital r: \( \R \).
```

What do brackets `\(` and `\)` do here? Are they required to call user-defined commands? But I am not using any brackets while using built-in commands like

```
\textbf{commands}
```

Can I write my custom command so that I can also use it without any brackets, like

```
\R
```

not

```
\( \R \)
```

Comment: `\(...\)` is an alternative (newer) syntax for math mode, only available in latex, instead of TeX's `$...$`.  It provides a couple of extra checks.  The command `\mathbb` can only be used in mathmode, so is needed when using this particular macro

Comment: Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510/15925

Comment: In the general case, you can search for it in the books. This one can be found in the LaTeX unofficial reference manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing `\( \R \)` is the same thing as typing `$ \R $`, and the `\mathbf` command is allowed only in math mode. Therefore, you will get an error if you use it outside that mode.

Comment: That is not 100% correct, `\(\) ` gives better error messages than `$... $`, sut since it is tedious to type most use `$... $`

Comment: Why some things do work out of `$` (like `\textbf`) and others do not (like new `\R`)?

Comment: That's another question. I suggest that you post it as such.

Comment: Why? I need to define a command, which can be used WITHOUT `\(` and `\)`, like `textbf`. It is second part of this question...

Comment: Indeed. You can define it as `\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}`.