Best Practice for Inline Math in LaTeX: \( ... \) vs. \$ ... \$
I'm currently writing a mathematical article for a journal in LaTeX and I'm trying to determine the best practice for writing inline math. I've seen both \( ... \) and $ ... $ used to denote inline math, and I'm curious about which one is generally considered better and why.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode
